# jquery .html() and javascript tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqplot

I am trying to export the content of a div with jQuery but it has a jqplot graph inside of it.

When I try to re-render it, all the elements of the graph like the name and values appear, but not the bar charts. I am currently using:

```
$('#exportable').html();
```

Here is the thing, if I include the javascript that is used to execute the chart, it duplicates all the data and overlaps itself.

If I don't, the graph won't appear, just the values.

I would post the code but there really isn't much to look at. I've been trying to experiment and googling for the past few hours. Maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing. Anything would help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `$('#exportable').html();`

Comment: Just to make sure, the bare is in the `"#exportable"-div`, locate the bar-charts with some developer tool (F12 in Chrome and IE). Otherwise it might help using `$("exportasble").empty()` instead.

Comment: Simply cloning the HTML wouldn't work in this case. The elements need the styling of jqplot in order to actually work properly.

Comment: @wumm It's a typo in the question. Sorry! :P

Comment: Is the graph built with HTML or with SVG? I'm not sure jQuery's `.html()` supports the latter.

Comment: It's with HTML and JS using jqPlot. I've gone ahead and used another method. Storing JSON and rebuilding it. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attempting to clone the chart, why not create another chart with the same data? See this for an example:

http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14727843/

Note that the "clone" button simply calls newPlot with the same data that was passed into the initial call, it doesn't attempt anything fancy, or look at the original contents of the plot.

Comment: Hi there, it's really a good idea however my options are quite limited. I need to save it in the database in one single text column and there is a table that comes along with it!

Comment: I ended up doing your method instead and even rebuilding the table. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you save the plotting data in the database instead of the HTML? And then render the chart when the user needs the page?